# Redirect websocket apache

Tags: apache, websocket, confluence

I am facing a WebSocket redirection issue in apache. Below configuration is redirecting the ws traffic and I am getting 101 response.

```
<Location /synchrony>
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine on  
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
   RewriteRule .* ws://domain.com:8089%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
</Location>
```

But I need to rewrite to the domain without specifying the port number. Have apache configuration set up on the domain for the same.But if I remove the port number 8089 from rewrite rule, I am getting below error.

[Mon Mar 26 04:31:47.812512 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 13643:tid 140652251637504] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: WS: attempt to connect to x.x.x.x:0 (*) failed
[Mon Mar 26 04:31:47.812568 2018] [proxy_wstunnel:error] [pid 13643:tid 140652251637504] [client x.x.x.x:53689] AH02452: failed to make connection to backend: domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your virtual host with below configuration:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)    ws://domain.com:8089/$1 [P,L]
```